# Is the set of all periodic functions with similar period, a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, periodic-functions

Let $S$ be the set of all the periodic function with period $T$, is it a vector space?

I know a vector space is a set that is closed under finite vector addition and scalar multiplication, I want to prove that $S$ is a vector space (I believe there's no counter-example)

Comment: There is no counter-example. $S$ is a vector space.

Comment: If you know what a vector space is, then why don't you try to prove that that specific set is a vector space?

Comment: You need to be careful with definitions here. Constant functions will be a part of your vector space. Do they have period $T$? I am fine with it if they do, I think Wikipedia agrees with that too.

Comment: @Pjotr5 should I prove it for them as a special case? Since any number is constant function's period, T must be too. I think it's arbitrary for constant functions,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f,g \in S$ and if $\alpha$ is a scalar then we have

$(f+g)(x+T)=f(x+T)+g(x+T)=f(x)+g(x)=(f+g)(x)$

and

$(\alpha f)(x+T)=\alpha f(x+T)= \alpha f(x)= (\alpha f)(x).$

Conclusion ?

Comment: Why the downvote ????????????????????????

Comment: @Fred I didn't downvote, but I guess downvoters didn't like the fact that you gave a full answer to a question where op didn't show any of his work

Comment: Yes, Alaheh learnt little from this apart from how to get someone to do their homework for them.

Comment: Why don't we need to check other axioms?